# Network Recovery doesn't always load the latest compatible Recovery partition

Tags: recovery, diskutil

I am using the Command-Option-R key-combination at start up to load up the latest Recovery Partition online, and then proceed to cloning disk-images using `asr` and `diskutil` in terminal.

Normally after Macs boot into Recovery, most of the Macs have the option to install OS "Ventura". But some Macs give the option to install "Big Sur", which is correlated with an issue when restoring disk-images.
All devices that prompt to install "Big Sur" instead of the latest OS fail to complete the restoration process with `asr` with the error that source has a `broken seal`, which seems to be a common issue with "Big Sur"

A current solution is to install "Big Sur" on those few Macs, then after the installation completes booting into Network Recovery again offers to install the latest OS -as expected- and my restoration script works fine.

Is there a solution to why not all Macs are loading the latest Recovery partition?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: All Macs are of the same model "MacBookPro15,1"